# Two onclick events with a PHP if and else statement - in one button

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement, dom-events

I have the above below already functional on my website. It works alright but right now, I want to create a kind of promo and if the display meets the criteria of the promo, I want it to display `onclick` `$htx`

```
<?php 
echo "<a href='javascript:;' onclick='pkgsPopup('http://'.$hLnk');' rel='nofollow'>";
?>
```

I have `$htx` pre defined to open a link `$dealpath` and if it does not meet that condition, I want it to open the default link - '$hLnk'

I have tried the code below and I had an error _ I mean the page will not load at all

```
 if ($htx) { echo "onclick=\'miaPopup('http://$dealPth');\'' }  else { echo 'onclick=\'pkgsPopup('http://$hLnk');\'' }";
```

I will really appreciate if someone can let me know how to do this without error using the PHP if/else statement.

Comment: Looks like you have an extra ' on both of your echo statements in the second code block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your second block of code a little cleaner. You were missing semi-colons in the PHP as well as matching escape characters ( a mix of apostrophes and quotes)

```
if ($htx) 
{ 
  echo "onclick=\'miaPopup('http://$dealPth');\'" ;
} 
else 
{ 
  echo "onclick=\'pkgsPopup('http://$hLnk');\'" ;
}
```

Comment: Hey Le_garry, You made the 1st response and I really appreciate it. I used the code below and I got it working: <?php 
   

          if ($htx){ 

    $onclick="miaPopup('http://$dealPth');";
    }

    else{ 

    $onclick="pkgsPopup('http://$hLnk');";

    }

      ?>

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. Please select the best answer and upvote those that are helpful! Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the echo pumping out a long string that makes no sense:

```
 if ($htx) { echo "onclick=\'miaPopup('http://$dealPth');\'' }  else { echo 'onclick=\'pkgsPopup('http://$hLnk');\'' }";
```

should read:

```
if ($htx) {
    echo "onclick='miaPopup(\'http://$dealPth\');'";
}  else {
    echo "onclick='pkgsPopup(\'http://$hLnk\');'";
}
```

You could simplify by saying

```
if ($htx) {
    $url = $dealPth;
} else {
    $url = $hLnk;
}
echo "onclick='pkgsPopup(\'http://$url\');'";
```

Comment: Thanks Robbie, I used your idea and it was a very tremendous help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (this code is not tested):

```
$onclick = ($htx ? 'miaPopup("http://'.$dealPth.'");'
            : 'pkgsPopup("http://'.$hLnk.'");');
echo "<a href='javascript:;' onclick='$onclick' rel='nofollow'>";
```

Comment: Thanks Cegfault. Your idea really helped. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if ($htx){ 

    $onclick="miaPopup('http://$dealPth');";
    }

    else{ 

    $onclick="pkgsPopup('http://$hLnk');";

    }";

echo "<a href='javascript:;' onclick='$onclick' rel='nofollow'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery

```
<a class='one <?=($cond?"two" : "")?>'>Link</link>

<script>

$(function(){
   $(".one").click(function(){
      //Class of one
    });

   $(".two").click(function(){
     //class of two
    })
})

</script>
```